# Which is more proper javascript syntax?

Tags: javascript, syntax

```
if (//some condition) {
//some code
} else {
//other code
}
```

or

```
if (//some condition) {
//some code
}
else {
//other code
}
```

Comment: i'm going to say yes.

Comment: You realize that 1) they're both completely identical 2) they both have syntax errors?

Comment: Yes, I definitely agree.

Comment: Still had one close vote left. Glad it went to this one.

Comment: trying hard to see any difference at all...

Comment: sorry i on accident forgot to change them, now they are different. Sorry about that :(

Comment: @chromedude: Well it's still gonna be closed anyway. **This kind of question has been asked to oblivion.**

Comment: @Zhang18 what is wrong with the code sharing? I just skimmed the page you referenced and I see no problem.

Comment: @BoltClock Maybe it has but I really am not sure how I would find it. I tried, but didn't get relevant results.

Comment: Personally, I think it's a perfectly acceptable question - as sometimes people may be confused or not introduced to the concept of coding standards (which would make it difficult to find the "oblivion" of answers out there). Basically, chromedude, they will perform the same - just be sure to use the same structure consistently over time and with your fellow developers. It'll save debugging time in the future to stay consistent.

Comment: @James Maroney Thanks! That is what I thought I was just making sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the first one isn't good, and I have the same feelings about the second one

Comment: ok, thanks. I am relatively new to javascript and I taught what I know to myself so on syntax I have some weird things so I wanted to fix this one if this one was wrong.